# OID claim is missing in Microsoft id_token claims

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with a couple of applications which are created in [apps.dev.microsoft.com](http://apps.dev.microsoft.com). The auth URL I am using is

```
https: //login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
 client_id={client_id}
 &redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
 &response_type=code id_token
 &state=state
 &nonce=c7a966a3-d63d-4348-8ab8-bd445b0e9bb1
 &response_mode=form_post
 &scope=openid email profile https://graph.microsoft.com/user.readBasic.all
```

In my use case, I am capturing `tid`, `oid`, `iss`, `sub`... claims from `id_token` claims.

For one of my application, with some users the `oid` claim is missing in the `id_token`. But I am able to get for other apps and I don't see any difference in creating apps.

What reasons might cause the `oid` claim to be missing?

Scopes I am using: `openid` `email` `user.read`

Answer (score 5):

The `oid` claim will only be returned if the scope `profile` was requested.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens):

> Because the `oid` allows multiple apps to correlate users, the `profile` scope is required in order to receive this claim.

For users where you don't receive the `oid` claim, check the token to make sure the `profile` scope is there. If it isn't there (and you've confirmed it was requested) then you can force the scopes for that token to be refreshed by adding `&prompt=consent` to the end of your authentication URI. This will force the user to re-consent to the scopes and ensure you're not getting a cached token.

Comment: Thank you Marc, its really helpful. As per your comment (forcing user to re-consent), user will going to see this consent for each login time. How should we control it, i mean is any way to capture info like user is consented or not.

Comment: I recently did a POC where we interrogated the JWT token to see if there were any missing scopes. If there were we redirected them back with `&prompt=consent`. Since they just logged in, it dropped them right into the Consent page. It did cause some "redirect flickering" in the browser as it bounced around but it was still quite tollorable.